# Laravel whereHas on multiple rows

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

```
$search = Workforce::whereHas('task_schedule', function($q) use($request){
        if($request->search_schedule_day != null){
            foreach($request->search_schedule_day as $day){
                /*$q->whereIn('schedule_day', 'like', '%'. $day .'%');*/
                var_dump($day);
            }
        }
        if($request->search_time_in != null){
            $q->where('schedule_time_in', 'like', '%' . $request->search_time_in . '%');
        }
        if($request->search_time_out != null){
            $q->where('schedule_time_out', 'like', '%' . $request->search_time_out . '%');
        }
    })
```

I am currently making an advanced search feature, and I have encountered this problem wherein I have an array of search_schedule[] . Then in the database, it is saved one day per row. How do I set a query for searching the days in that array ?

## Edit

```
            if($request->search_schedule_day != null){
            foreach($request->search_schedule_day as $day){
                /*$q->whereIn('schedule_day', 'like', '%'. $day .'%');*/
                var_dump($day);
            }
        }
```

How can I set a query in the above block of code wherein it checks rows in database where column = $request->search_schedule_day

Comment: where exactly is your problem? please elaborate further.

Comment: @Wreigh here.

if($request->search_schedule_day != null){
            foreach($request->search_schedule_day as $day){
                /*$q->whereIn('schedule_day', 'like', '%'. $day .'%');*/
                var_dump($day);
            }
        }

How can I set a query wherein it checks rows in database where column = $request->search_schedule_day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to check whether the **model**'s `schedule_day` is present in `$request->search_schedule_day`, you can try this:

```
if($request->search_schedule_day != null) {
    $q->where(function($query)use($request) { // group orWheres
        for ($request->search_schedule_date as $day) {
            $query->orWhere('schedule_day', $day);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I haven't thought of using another where, then a foreach inside. That one solved my problem. Thank you again.